# Close a spatial line into a polygon using a shapefile

Tags: r, gis, shapefile

I have a SpatialLinesDataFrame that was produced from a contour of marine environmental data.  The contour is not closed where it meets land.  I would like to close the contour so that I can calculate the area within the contour.  I have a shapefile for the coastline.

So, I would like to use the coastline shapefile to close the contour lines.

Edit:  Here's an image illustrating what I am trying to do.  The black line is the contour and the red is the coastline.  I want the area enclosed by the black areas. [image]

Comment: To get most out of SO, provide example data and what code you tried so far. Without specifics, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221822/how-to-bound-the-outer-area-of-voronoi-polygons-and-intersect-with-map-data